# Invalid object name 'Student' while running IIS webservice using SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2005, iis, connection-string, database-permissions

I created a web-service using asp.NET and the database is created using SQL Server 2005. Then I published it to be able to use it from an Android device. I used the IIS Manager to publish it as local IIS. the publishing is done well but when I try to Browse my web-service, the home page of the web-service appears in the browser. But when I try to test one of the methods that uses the database to retrieve some data, (Select * from Student) where Student is a table in my SQL Server 2005 database, an error page appears stating that: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Student'.

I searched and found some people said that I should add (dbo.) in the query (Select * from dbo.Student) but it doesn't work  too. the same error occured: Invalid object name 'dbo.Student'.

The result of the query returned correctly from Visual Studio when right-clicking the file *.asmx and choose to View in Browser. But it's not returned from the published web-service.

This is my connectionString

Should I give permissions somewhere?! I do't know how to do permissions on the database tables.

Any help will be appreciated.
THanks..

Comment: @marc_s Sorry if annoying. But could you please try to help me with my problem mentioned above.

Comment: this is my connectionString: <add name="sbms" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Could you please help me with my problem mentioned above.

Comment: @Mobility Could you please help me with my problem mentioned above.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Could you please help me with my problem mentioned above.